# What is a binary relation like whose reflexive transitive closure is a partial order?

Tags: order-theory, relations

Let $R$ be a reflexive binary relation and $R^*$ be its reflexive transitive closure.  The question is what is the equivalent condition in terms of $R$ to $R^*$ being a partial order.

Intuitively, a reflexive transitive closure adds reflexivity and transitivity to the original relation.  But just because $R$ is antisymmetric doesn't mean $R^*$ is a partial order.

Comment: $R$ (not counting the loops) must not have any directed cycles.

Comment: Does it have a special name?

Answer (score 1):

[Directed acyclic graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph) (often abbreviated to DAG).